# Dashboard Refresh to Chatter

Tags: chatter

Does anyone know if there is a way to have a dashboard refresh daily and automatically post to Chatter? It would be like scheduling a dashboard, but instead of emailing it to anyone, it would post to a Chatter feed...

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at [dashboard chatter feeds](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_post_to_dashboard_feed.htm)?

I haven't tried it but looks like combination of scheduled dashboard refreshes (meaning you'd still might have to "spam" one user?) and this could do the trick.

Setup -> Customize -> Chatter -> Feed Tracking -> Dashboard (if you don't have it ticked already).

> Only metrics and gauges with conditional highlighting set are eligible
>   for following. When you follow a dashboard, you automatically follow
>   all eligible components. (...) When the dashboard is refreshed, if the
>   value for a followed component crosses a breakpoint, an alert is
>   posted to your Chatter feed. If the component’s dashboard is filtered,
>   you receive an update only when the component is refreshed in
>   unfiltered mode.

So I guess you wouldn't see the changes for whole dashboard, just metric/gauge pieces (probably so the Chatter post is not an one giant image).